# Accelerate UDF in xlwings

Tags: python, xlwings

I tried to experiment some features from Xlwings. I would like to use a common function from numpy which allowed to interpolate quickly (numpy.interp).

```
@xlfunc
def interp(x, xp,yp):
    """Interpolate vector x on vector (xp,yp)"""
    y=np.interp(x,xp,yp)
    return y

@xlfunc
def random():
    """Returns a random number between 0 and 1"""
    x=np.random.randn()
    return x
```

For instance, I create two vectors (xp, yp) like this (in Excel)
800 rows

```
First Column Second Column
0    =random()
1    =random()
2    =random()
3    =random()
4    =random()
5    =random()
[...]
```

In the third columns I create another vector (60 row), with random number bewteen 0 and 800 (ranked in ascending order)
Which give me something like this :

```
Third Column    
17.2    
52.6    
75.8    
[...]
```

I would like to interpolate the third column into the first column. So

```
Fourth Column    
=interp(C1,A1:A800,B1:B800)    
=interp(C2,A1:A800,B1:B800)    
=interp(C3,A1:A800,B1:B800)    
[...]
```

It's easy to do this. But if I have 10 or more columns to interpolate it could take too much time. I am sure there is a better way to do this. An idea ?

Thanks for your help !

**edit :**

I tried this but doesn't work at "xw.Range[...].value=y"

```
@xw.xlfunc
def interpbis(x, xp,yp):
    """Interpolate scalar x on vector (xp,yp)"""
    thisWB=xw.Workbook.active()
    thisSlctn=thisWB.get_selection(asarray=True)
    sheet=thisSlctn.xl_sheet.name
    r = thisSlctn.row
    c = thisSlctn.column
    y=np.interp(x,xp,yp)
    xw.Range(sheet,(r,c)).value=y
    return None
```

Comment: Have you tried it and found some actual performance issues?

Comment: Yes, indeed. Actualy, when I launch all the calculation, it take as long as in VBA (I imagine it's because the UDF is built to run on each cell one by one). Maybe if I could work with range it'll be faster, but I don't know how to do this easily.

Comment: [EDIT]. If I could get the active cell adress I could do something like Range(ActiveCell).table=ar with ar an array with the resut ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is: Use Excel's array functions.

The long answer is:
First, update to xlwings v0.6.4 (otherwise what I am going to show for `random()` will not work). Then change your functions as follows:

```
from xlwings import Application, Workbook, xlfunc
import numpy as np

@xlfunc
def interp(x, xp, yp):
    """Interpolate vector x on vector (xp,yp)"""
    y = np.interp(x, xp, yp)
    return y[:, np.newaxis]  # column orientation

@xlfunc
def random():
    """Returns a random number between 0 and 1"""
    app = Application(Workbook.caller())
    # We shall make this easier in a future release (getting the array dimensions)
    r = app.xl_app.Caller.Rows.Count
    c = app.xl_app.Caller.Columns.Count
    x = np.random.randn(r, c)
    return x
```

Now use array formulas in Excel as described [here](http://docs.xlwings.org/udfs.html#array-formulas-i-without-numpy) (`Ctrl+Shift+Enter`).

Comment: Thanks a lot that's work great :) And it's really quick

Comment: I also tried something like this but I get an "Erreur Automation" on the Range.Value line. If you have some ideads                                                                                              `xw.xlfunc
    def interpbis(x, xp,yp):
        """Interpolate scalar x on vector (xp,yp)"""
       thisWB=xw.Workbook.active()
        thisSlctn=thisWB.get_selection(asarray=True)
        y=np.interp(x,xp,yp)
        thisSlctn.value=y

Comment: `thisSlctn.xl_sheet.name` returns an object from pywin32 or appscript (depending on the platform you are). you would have to replace it with something like `thisWB.name` in your sample.

Comment: Sorry, that should read `thisWB.active_sheet.name`, but you can also use `thisWB.active_sheet` directly in `Range()`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately it's still block on the line 'xw.Range() = y" :/

Comment: Hi, do you know if there is a solution ? Thanks again for your help.